# SQL update column in row based on row number

Tags: sql

I am trying to sanitize a database I have for testing purposes, and want to update a column (`name`) to something like `Name <rownumber>`.

I have given it a go myself, but it cycles through all the rows and ends up naming them all the same at the end `Name 323`; 323 being the total number of rows.

Some direction would be very helpful.

This is what I have at the moment

Should I not be doing a while for each row in the table?

```
DECLARE @counter INT = 2
DECLARE @rows int
DECLARE @CustCode varchar(20)
DECLARE @CustName varchar(128)
DECLARE @CustID varchar(10) 

SELECT @rows = COUNT(*) FROM Customer

WHILE @counter <= @rows
BEGIN
    SELECT @CustID = CustomerID FROM Customer
    SET @CustCode = 'CustCode' + @CustID
    SET @CustName = 'Customer Description ' + @CustID
        
    SET @CustName = 'Customer Description ' + @CustID

    UPDATE Customer 
    SET CustomerCode = @CustCode, 
        CustomerDescription = @CustName

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Comment: Well - your `UPDATE` doesn't have a `WHERE` clause - so you're updating the **whole** table each time the code runs through one of the cycles in `WHILE...`... And also - the initial  `SELECT @CustID = ....` will most likely keep selecting the same `CustomerID` over and over and over again....

Comment: For the `UPDATE`, should it be closer to `update Customer set CustomerCode = @CustCode, CustomerDescription = @CustName  where CustomerID = @CustID`?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, it would be **much better** to use **ONE, set-based** statement for this. You're not using any specific additional information (like a row number - as mentioned in your post) - you're just concatenating fixed text like `Cust Code` and `Customer Description`) with the already existing `CustomerId` - so a simple `UPDATE` statement like this would do (and would update everything in one go):

```
UPDATE dbo.Customer
SET CustomerCode = CONCAT('Cust Code ', CustomerId),
    CustomerDescription = CONCAT('Customer Description ', CustomerId);
```

Comment: Ah BRILLIANT! Thank you! I didn't know about the `CONCAT()` function! Works a treat!